# Generic mapping of types in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, type-conversion, type-safety

lets imagine type T:

```
type T = {
  prop1: (s: S) => T1,
  prop2: (s: S) => T2,
  prop3: (s: S) => T3,
}
```

and now lets imagine type W

```
type W = (s: S) => {
    prop1: T1,
    prop2: T2,
    prop3: T3,
}
```

its easy to write a function that maps T to W by hand,

is it possible to write generic type sefe version of it in typescript?

```
function x(t: T): W {
  return funtion(s: S) {
    prop1: t.prop1(s),
    prop2: t.prop2(s)
    prop3: t.prop3(s)
  }
}
```

what kind of feature language is missing to facilitate this, something like higher order generic types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed write a generic version of this in TypeScript:

```
function x<S, V>(t: {[K in keyof V]: (s: S) => V[K]}): (s: S) => V {
  return function(s: S): V {
    const ret = {} as V;
    Object.keys(t).forEach((k: keyof V) => {
      ret[k] = t[k](s);
    })
    return ret;
  }
} 

const xSpecific: (t: T) => W = x; // okay
```

Note that `V` is the return type of your `W` function.  (So `W` is essentially the same as `(s: S) => V`.)  And the input to `x` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) corresponding to `T`: it has the same keys as `V`, but its values are functions from `S` to the corresponding properties of `V`.

You can get away with having the function input being a mapped type and the output being an unmapped one because TypeScript supports [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types).  Otherwise you'd need something like [the proposed "extended `typeof`" feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606) to derive `W` from `T` generically.  (This might be the missing language feature to which you're alluding.)

As for the implementation, I'm looping over the keys of `t` and applying each function `t[k]` to the input `s`.

And `xSpecific` is the same as `x` narrowed to the particular `T` and `W` types you posted.  This compiles because TypeScript recognizes that the generic `x` is compatible.

---

Now for the caveats and fine print.  Unfortunately, the compiler isn't able to reliably infer the type of `S` from `x` directly.  If you just call the generic `x()` with a `T` input, you get this:

```
declare const t: T;
const w = x(t); // (s: {}) => { prop1: T1; prop2: T2; prop3: T3; }
```

The `w` is not exactly a `W`... it accepts any input, not just an `S`.  If you really need to narrow the type of input, you'll have to do it yourself by manually specifying the generic parameters:

```
const w = x<S, {prop1: T1, prop2: T2, prop3: T3}>(t);
```

which is ugly, or narrowing the resulting `w` manually by assertion or annotation:

```
const w: W = x(t);
```

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: sure it help, essentially, you did one thing witch I never do :) witch maybe I should consider more often, you've used "as" witch it ok in this context.

Comment: stupid stack:) I had to split my answer...
this caveat, you witch s:{} signature, this is not cool, but I know that there are several issues regarding similar stuff in Typescript GitHub. one more thing, this V, that this maps to correct types of return values of props is not so obvious also. another lesson is that I've tried to declare generic constraint on V instead of declaring shape of parameter t directly, there's still too much C# in my head ;)

Comment: in my situation, I can, put s:S in x signature and call this returned function immediately inside x, so this caveat can be neglected.