# Mapping distributive types in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following type declaration:

```
export type Interval = '1m' | '3m' | '5m' | '15m' | '30m' | '1h' | '2h' | '4h' | '6h' | '8h' | '12h' | '1d' | '3d' | '1w' | '1M'
```

Now I would like to create a type mapper similar to the following:

```
export type Mapping<T extends string, K> = { [k in keyof T]: K } // Doesn't work
```

that would allow to do the following:

```
export type IntervalValue = MappingOf<Interval, number>;

export const IntervalValue: MappingOf<Interval, number> = {
    '1m': 1000 * 60 * 1,
    '3m': 1000 * 60 * 3,
    '5m': 1000 * 60 * 5,
    '15m': 1000 * 60 * 15,
    '30m': 1000 * 60 * 30,
    '1h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1,
    '2h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
    '4h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 4,
    '6h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6,
    '8h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 8,
    '12h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12,
    '1d': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1,
    '3d': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3,
    '1w': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1,
    '1M': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 1,
}

// Later I would do the following
const interval: Interval = '1m'
const intervalValue: IntervalValue = IntervalValue[interval]
// ... do something with intervalValue ...
```

Unfortunately current implementation of `MappingOf` results with `IntervalValue` equal to `Interval` type itself... I.e. now:

```
IntervalValue is '1m' | '3m' | '5m' | '15m' | '30m' | '1h' | '2h' | '4h' | '6h' | '8h' | '12h' | '1d' | '3d' | '1w' | '1M'
```

Comment: You seem to use "distributive types" to mean something like "union types" but I'm not sure.  In any case, your question had nothing to do with mapping over both unions of strings and also the keys of objects passed in, so I don't see how your edited in answer applies.  Finally, with your `MapOf<T, K>` you get this behavior: `const IntervalValues: MapOf<Intervals, number> = { "2h": 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2 };`... that is not an error; you only need one of the `Intervals` as a key... is that really what you want?

Comment: I was trying to refer to original naming used in documentation, sorry. I had problems with mapping a union type to an object of fields defined by union type keys. On the other hand I had other case where I needed to also map a DTO (Data transfer object) to a config object, i.e. the config object has the same list of fields but instead of values it had configuration objects, so I needed both the mapper from union type and mapper of object type which you don't get out of the box. That's why I've included the example of combined mapper which I removed due to very pronounced friction...

Comment: I've also renamed plural type names to singular, plural seemed odd...

Comment: I wasn't trying to talk about plurals (e.g., `Intervals` vs `Interval`) but the issue that `type MapOf<T, K> = T extends string ? Record<T, K> : Record<keyof T, K>;` will [distribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) over `T` if it's a union, which is probably not what you want.  `MapOf<"a"|"b", string>` will become `{a: string} | {b: string}` and not `{a: string; b: string}`.  Which means that `{a: "foo"}` is a valid `MapOf<"a"|"b", string>`, whereas presumably you'd want an error that it's missing the `b` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map over `T` not `keyof T`:

```
export type Intervals = '1m' | '3m' | '5m' | '15m' | '30m' | '1h' | '2h' | '4h' | '6h' | '8h' | '12h' | '1d' | '3d' | '1w' | '1M'

export type MappingOf<T extends string, K> = { [k in T]: K } 

export type IntervalValues = MappingOf<Intervals, number>;

export const IntervalValues: MappingOf<Intervals, number> = {
    '1m': 1000 * 60 * 1,
    '3m': 1000 * 60 * 3,
    '5m': 1000 * 60 * 5,
    '15m': 1000 * 60 * 15,
    '30m': 1000 * 60 * 30,
    '1h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1,
    '2h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
    '4h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 4,
    '6h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6,
    '8h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 8,
    '12h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12,
    '1d': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1,
    '3d': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3,
    '1w': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1,
    '1M': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 1,
}
```

Your `MappingOf` type is equivalent to `Record` I would recommend using that :

```
export type Intervals = '1m' | '3m' | '5m' | '15m' | '30m' | '1h' | '2h' | '4h' | '6h' | '8h' | '12h' | '1d' | '3d' | '1w' | '1M'



export const IntervalValues: Record<Intervals, number> = {
    '1m': 1000 * 60 * 1,
    '3m': 1000 * 60 * 3,
    '5m': 1000 * 60 * 5,
    '15m': 1000 * 60 * 15,
    '30m': 1000 * 60 * 30,
    '1h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 1,
    '2h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
    '4h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 4,
    '6h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 6,
    '8h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 8,
    '12h': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 12,
    '1d': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1,
    '3d': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3,
    '1w': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1,
    '1M': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 1,
}
```

Comment: I've eventually ended up with defining resulting type as: `export type Mapping<T, K> = T extends string ? Record<T, K> : Record<keyof T, K>;` it works both on distributive types and Objects, please update your answer with this result for the sake of others

Comment: Why would it help others to have a version that maps over either-strings-or-objects if that wasn’t part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found an answer in [Generic mapping of types in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130717/generic-mapping-of-types-in-typescript) with reference to official documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types

The resulting type looks like the following:

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
}
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
}
```